# The underlying provider failed on Open in SQL Server 2008 remotely

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

The underlying provider failed on Open in SQL Server 2008  remotely

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder =new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlBuilder.DataSource = "mary\SQL2008";
sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "StudentDB";
sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
sqlBuilder.UserID = "sa";
sqlBuilder.Password = "mar";
sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = "EntityFramework";
string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =new  EntityConnectionStringBuilder();`enter code here`
entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;
entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/Student.csdl|res://*/Student.ssdl|res://*/Student.msl";
EntityConnection en = new  EntityConnection();
```

Comment: Make sure connection string is correct.

Comment: Can you post your connection string (minus any identifying info)? I'd also check to make sure that the server allows remote connections. It very likely does but it's worth a look.